# How to put a value from a variable to a register?

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, nasm

I want to compare the end character of my string to a period.

I counted the length of the string and saved it in a variable named `strlen`. So, I did `cmp [string + strlen], '.'`, but it didn't work, Then, I tried moving `strlen` to a register, but it didnt work as well. The program crashes. I'm using x86 32-bit Windows 10 architecture

```
MOV BL, [strlen-1]      ;the length of the string minus 1 so i would end up 
                         in the last character of the string
cmp [string + BL], '.'
JE func1
```

Comment: You can't use `bl` in an addressing mode. Please put your actual code in the question..

Comment: yeah ive tried using eax too but its not working as well

Comment: Use registers, not a static `[strlen]`.  That's what registers are for.  And especially don't increment a memory location inside a loop; that's a major bottleneck (like 6 cycles instead of 1.)  You're already incrementing a pointer, so just do a pointer subtraction at the end if you want to get the length, given a pointer to the start and end.

Comment: Your edit makes the question and answer make no sense.  This won't assemble (because there was a mistake in the first version of the answer that you copied, fixed now), and the answer is answering the old version of your question.  I rolled it back, but actually ` [string + BL]` won't assemble either, so that isn't a [mcve] of your code that assembled + ran but crashed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MOV BL, [strlen-1]
```

This isn't actually doing what you think it's doing. It's not storing the value of `strlen - 1` in `bl`. Rather, it is storing the value at the ***address*** `strlen - 1` in `bl`.

If you know C, it is the difference between:

```
byte* strlen = ...;
BL = *strlen - 1;
```

and:

```
byte* strlen = ...;
BL = *(strlen - 1);
```

In assembly notation, you can think of the brackets (`[...]`) as meaning "address to dereference", where "address" is interchangeable with "memory location"—like a pointer in C.

If you want to subtract 1 from the actual *value* of `strlen`, then you need to load the value into a register first, and then subtract 1 from it.

In C:

```
byte* strlen = ...;
bl  = *strlen;
bl -= 1;
```

In assembly:

```
movzx ebx, BYTE PTR [strlen]
sub   ebx, 1                     ; (or dec ebx)
```

The `BL` register will now contain the length of the string, minus 1. So, you can do:

```
mov  al, BYTE PTR [startOfString + ebx]      ; al = startOfString[bl]
```

to load the last character in the string (which start at address `startOfString`) into the variable `al`.

Then, follow it up with:

```
cmp  al, '.'
```

to set flags. Or, as you had it originally, you could use a CISC-style instruction that combines the load with the comparison:

```
cmp  BYTE PTR [startOfString + ebx], '.'
```

Comment: You can't use `bl` in an addressing mode, so you need to use `movzx ebx, BYTE PTR [strlen]` and then use `ebx` in the addressing mode.

Comment: In assembly, you can do the `-1` with the 2nd addressing mode (instead of the first).  You don't need a `dec` or `sub`.  `mov  al, [startOfString - 1 + ebx]`.  The addressing mode already includes a `disp32` absolute address, so there's zero cost to doing this and having the linker fill in the disp32 with an offset from the symbol.